# How to set up new PC without entering any Microsoft account?

Tags: windows

I just got a new PC, turned it on, was going through setup, and got to the point where they were forcing me to set up a Microsoft account. How can I skip this? I don't seem to see any options!

Comment: See https://www.xda-developers.com/windows-11-microsoft-local-account/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me (and is probably quicker than some of the other methods I've seen but haven't tried):

> 1. Under "Sign in", enter "no@thankyou.com" > Click "Next"
> 2. Enter any password > Click "Sign in"
> 3. Now they should give you the message below > Click "Next"
>
> [image]

[Source](https://www.neowin.net/news/bypass-microsoft-account-requirement-when-setting-up-windows-11-with-internet/)